# Compare the different representations of the same URI

Tags: c#, web-services, ip-address

We have the following situation:

The clients are sending events / messages to the server over a webservice. The server can identify the clients according to the "Sender URI". The server must now distribute the message to the "interested listeners".

Now it can be that a client says it is e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/ on the server this client is configured with http://localhost:8000.
Uri.Compare( ) and Uri.Equals return both false.

Does anybody knows an algorithm who can identify the URI with all its representations? I mean Localhost == 127.0.0.1 == "Real IP" == "DNS-Name" ?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because nobody has posted an answer yet, I will stay with my own made "algorithm" / method which tries to compare all different representations.

What I found out: At the server it is not possible to determine in all cases a remote URL. It can be that the user - account or the subnetwork the server is in, does not have enough privileges to determine e.g. which IP is behind the Active Directory Name.

So there will be always the problem that the server needs a manually filled file or so, which it uses as a base to determine if it knows the sender-URI.